# Indicate Landmarks on a Cummulative Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to indicate on a curve some landmarks of scores so that it is easily seen at a glance that a certain number of students had, say, 50% and/or 70%, based on my cummulative score. I tried the below code but I couldn't make headway with it. Any assistance would be much appreciated:

```
cum_score = np.cumsum(score)
plt.step(range(len(cum_score)), cum_score)
plt.xlabel('Score')
plt.ylabel('Cum Score') 
plt.annotate("50%", (5, cum_score[50]))
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Plot of Cumulative Score of nth value versus the n')
plt.show()
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your expected output, and how does it differ from what this code produces?

Comment: The plot works fine but I do not have the annotated point in the output. I actually wish it has the annotated point.